# Why can I access some arguments from parent in child class (and some not)?

Tags: python, inheritance

I've been experimenting and trying to find answers, but still don't understand why I can access some args that were not passed to the child class and some not.

Given this code:

```
class Signals(object):
    
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        super().__init__()

        self.numbers = numbers
        self.factor = 2

    def get_calculations(self):
        self.beau = Beau(self.numbers)
        self.beau.calculation()
       
        self.jolais = Jolais()
        self.jolais.calculation()
        
        print("self.beau.value", self.beau.value)
        print("self.beau.avg", self.beau.avg)
        print("self.jolais.value", self.jolais.value)
        print("self.jolais.avg", self.jolais.avg)


class Beau(Signals):
    
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        super().__init__(numbers)

    def calculation(self):
        numbers = self.numbers
        factor = self.factor
        
        self.value = sum(numbers) * factor
        self.avg = self.value/len(numbers)
        
class Jolais(Signals):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def calculation(self):

        numbers = [1,1,1]
        if type(self.numbers) == type(list()):
            numbers = self.numbers
        factor = self.factor
        
        self.value = sum(numbers) * factor
        self.avg = self.value/len(numbers)

Signals([1,2,3]).get_calculations()
```

..won't work: `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numbers'`

Replacing this bit with:

```
class Jolais(Signals):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("anything")
```

..will give me the expected result:

```
self.beau.value 12
self.beau.avg 4.0
self.jolais.value 6
self.jolais.avg 2.0
```

So why can I access `self.factor` even if it's not passed and `self.numbers` not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your intentions are with your code but you seem to have a class hierarchy where the base class also tries to create instances of its children, which seems odd.

Assuming you want a hierarchy where Beau and Jolais do different/more specialized calcuations, this works:

```
class Signals(object):
    
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        super().__init__()

        self.numbers = numbers
        self.factor = 2
        self.value = None
        self.avg = None
        
    def printvalues(self):
        print("value", self.value)
        print("avg", self.avg)
        
    def calculation(self):
        raise Exception( "Calculation not implemented in Signal")

class Beau(Signals):
    
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        super().__init__(numbers)
        self.factor = 3

    def calculation(self):
        numbers = self.numbers
        factor = self.factor
        
        self.value = sum(numbers) * factor
        self.avg = self.value/len(numbers)
        
class Jolais(Signals):
    
    def __init__(self,numbers):
        super().__init__(numbers)
        # gave this a different factor from Beau
        self.factor = -4

    def calculation(self):

        numbers = [1,1,1]
        if type(self.numbers) == type(list()):
            numbers = self.numbers
        factor = self.factor
        self.value = sum(numbers) * factor
        self.avg = self.value/len(numbers)


beau = Beau([1,2,3])
jolais = Jolais([5,6,7])

print( "Beau" )
beau.printvalues()
beau.calculation()
beau.printvalues()

print( "Jolais" )
jolais.printvalues()
jolais.calculation()
jolais.printvalues()
```

Result:

```
Beau
value None
avg None
value 18
avg 6.0
Jolais
value None
avg None
value -72
avg -24.0
```

Comment: But why can I access the parents' `self.factor` without initializing it?
Or differently asked: Why do I have to initialize `self.numbers` but not `self.factor` in the child class?